# Azure Devops deploying web app to a server - how to also update database

Tags: sql-server, iis, azure-devops, virtual-machine, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a web app which due to budgetary reasons is running on a windows VM (IIS) with its database also running in SQL Server on the same server.

We have a build pipeline set up in Azure Devops which builds the web app and then creates an idempotent SQL migration file (We use Entity Framework), both the compiled app and the SQL file are copied into the build artefact.

We then have a release pipeline which deploys the web app into IIS on the server.

What I cant figure out is how to get the SQL file run into the database.

I have tried the "SQL Database Deploy" task but that seems to only want a .dacpac file, or the path of a SQL file which is already on the server - I dont seem to be able to give it a file that exists on the build machine to execute remotely.

I know that because we are using EF I could just make the application do its migrations on startup but that means that the app needs to run as a user with schema privileges which we don't really want, currently the app is only a data reader/writer.

Is there some mechanism that I can take the SQL script from the build artefact and run it on the remote VM? If not, what are my options for getting the file onto the VM so that I can run it using the "SQL Database Deploy" task? I don't want to deploy it with the web app as although its a small risk we don't want it lingering in a public folder.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can do anything you want with Azure DevOps. You could write a Powershell file to connect to SQL Server and execute the .sql if you want to. Or write a .NET console app to do it. There's so many possibilities for how to get this done: you just need to decide how you want this to work and then make it happen.

Comment: To clarify the SQL server is not public, so we cant just connect and run the SQL in from powershell, whatever we do needs to be run either on the box, or If possible via an agent the same way as the web deployment is done).

With the .net console app we have the same issue - whats the best way to deploy it and then trigger it from the pipeline?

Ideally Im looking for tried and tested (normal?) ways of doing this, it cant be a new problem, we do it with Azure SQL DBs all the time, I just have no idea how to do it on a VM.

Comment: You have a mechanism for running things on the box. That's what the agents are for. As for how to authenticate to the SQL Server, you can either use SQL Auth or Windows Auth. Obviously if you use Windows Auth, the agent service will need to run as an account that has access to the DB server.

Comment: Again: you can do anything you want. It's up to you to decide how you want to do it, and go make it happen. Our  team has a whole application dedicated to receiving migration files and figuring out which DB's to apply them to. [Stack Overflow has their own way](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/05/03/stack-overflow-how-we-do-deployment-2016-edition/#database-migrations). Instead of asking what everyone else does, instead, *how do you want to do it?*

Comment: You seem to be asking for some "standard" or "best practice" way of doing things. It doesn't exist. There's no organizational body that says "You shall update your database for your application according to our rules". Instead, it's on you to figure out what works best for you/your team/your organization.

Comment: Ahh, ok, something you said there clicked - I was thinking of the agent purely as a mechanism to deploy the database, I didnt realise that I could use it to execure PowerShell remotely on the machine - In which case I guess I can use Invoke-Sqlcmd